# sprite image change with delay time in cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

am developing ipad game. i want to change the three image with delay time , when collision detection happens

am tryed this tutorial for changing animation , http://getsetgames.com/2010/04/18/how-to-animate-sprites-in-cocos2d/

but its terminating the app.

any other way is there to do like this?

Answer (score 0):

There is an example of sprite animation in cocos2d examples (SpriteTest example - animated dragon).